# Subgroups of multiplicative groups of the finite field with Mersenne prime order

Tags: finite-groups, finite-fields

I have a question about properties of the multiplicative groups.

Let we have finite field of prime order $2^k$ -1. $k$ is co-prime with $$\frac{2^k-2}{k}$$.

It is clear that multiplicative group of such field has subgroup of order.

$$\frac{2^k-2}{k}$$.

How it is possible to find formula for generator $g$ of this subgroup (this subgroup is always cyclic) ?

For example for $k=5$ $g=6$
For example for $k=7$ $g=24$

Comment: The equality $k = \frac{2^k - 2}k$ is obviously false.  (For example, as you say, for $k = 5$ it does not work.)  What do you mean?

Comment: Fixed my mistake , thanks

Comment: Note that $18^{18} \equiv 2 \pmod{2^7 - 1}$, so I think your conjecture fails for the case $k = 7$, $g = 18$ that you specify.

Comment: 1 18 70 117 74 62 100 22 15 16 34 104 94 41 103 76 98 113

Comment: I just wrote simple computer script

Comment: Yes, your computations are correct, and they show that the order of $18$ modulo $127$ is not less than $18$; but, as you can tell by going one step further, it's not $18$, either.  In fact, the order of $18$ modulo $127$ is $63$.

Comment: Correct my bad.
Anyway the question is the same.

Comment: How can the question be the same?  You've made a conjecture, and shown that it is false.

Comment: 24 68 108 52 105 107 28 37 126 103 59 19 75 22 20 99 90 1

Comment: The question is the same:
how to find generator for this subgroup ?

Comment: OK, I see that you have changed the question to remove the incorrect conjecture; now it makes sense.  The subgroup *is* cyclic—all finite subgroups of multiplicative groups of fields are—so there is no need to gather evidence for the *existence* of $g$.  My suspicion is that this is probably not much easier than finding a primitive generator for a random $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$, which is hard, but I have no evidence for that.  It may be interesting even to see if you can come up with an $\mathrm o(2^k/k)$ algorithm for testing membership in this subgroup (but I'm no expert; it may be known).

Comment: For example generator for subgroup of order $k$ is clear - it is always 2.

Comment: May be there is some interesting property for described subgroup ?

Comment: You might as well ask for a generator $x$ for the whole multiplicative group of the field, and then take $x^{k}$.

Comment: The whole multiplicative group is actually

$C_k x C_{\frac{2^k-2}{k}}$

And I thought that may be there are some interesting properties

Comment: @LSpice Testing membership is easy, as the group just consists of all $x$ such that $x^{(2^k-2)/k}=1$.

Comment: Is it possible that $g = 2^{t}*3$ ?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, right, but how fast can you perform that exponentiation?  (Faster than $\mathrm O(2^k/k)$, obviously, now that I think about it; but, yes, testing that property quickly is what I had in mind.)

Comment: @LSpice Quite fast (in time $\tilde O(k^2)$ or so). This is just modular exponentiation.

Comment: @AVT The multiplicative group is *not* $C_k\times C_{(2^k-2)/k}$ if $k$ is a Wieferich prime; are you saying that this can’t happen? ($2^k-1$ itself cannot be Wieferich, but this is something else.)

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, right, I know that modular exponentiation is fast.  That's why I was suggesting that a less difficult task than finding a generator—I assumed the question was how to find it *quickly*, since otherwise you can do as @‍GeoffRobinson suggests—might be to seek a *faster* test for membership than just exponentiation.

Comment: @Emil Jeřábek
Sorry don't understand your point


Would be appreciative for such example of $k$

Comment: I can’t give you an example, as only two Wieferich primes are known. But anyway, the multiplicative group is $C_{2^k-2}$, which is isomorphic to $C_k\times C_{(2^k-2)/k}$ only if $k$ is coprime to $(2^k-2)/k$, and there is no a priori reason this should be the case.

Comment: Modified question, added condition.

Comment: What is order of $3$ in such multiplicative groups ?

Comment: @AVT Can you clarify what you mean by "how to find"? Do you mean a fast algorithm? etc.

Comment: no, I mean some formula

Comment: hypothesis: this is $3*2^t$ for some $t$

Comment: The multiplicative group can be represented as table
Rows: cosets for $C_k$
Columns: cosets for $C_{\frac{2^{k}-2}{k}}$






I know the generator for rows, but don't know the generator for columns

if I find it - any element would be represented as $g^{r}*2^{s}$ for some $r,s$